# Fire Event When Element Is Dropped On

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm creating a control for my app that has several icons. You drag a button onto the icon that represents the action you want to take. However, I can't figure out how to get it to actually fire the event. I've followed the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.drop.aspx) but it doesn't fire the `Drop` event. Is there an easy way to know when *anything* is dropped on the element? (I don't care what is dropped; the only draggable element is the button.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.  I programmed a drag and drop and was able to get the all of the drag/drop related events:  DragEnter, DragOver, DragLeave, and DropCompleted, to fire.  The Drop event, however, never fired.  I felt that the documentation, as you discovered, is weak on this. It sent me down many dead ends. Then I found, after trial and error, that placing this line of code:

```
e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Move;
```

into the DragOver and DragLeave event handlers allowed the subsequent Drop event handler to fire.  I admit that I do not fully understand why.  I'm still working on figuring out what's going on here.  But I did get the drop event to fire.

Comment: Hmmm... My DragEnter event won't fire either. How were you doing the drag-drop? I'm using the ManipulationDelta event.

Comment: My program drags/drops images in a grid.  I set the appropriate drag/drop properties for each Image (a UIElement):
<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="{StaticResource imageSource}"AllowDrop="True"  Drop="DropQueen"  CanDrag="True" DragEnter ="Image_DragEnter" DragLeave="Image_DragLeave" DragOver="Image_DragOver" DragStarting="Image_DragStarting" DropCompleted="Image_DropCompleted" />
I added code for each of the drag related event handlers.  It seems that the system generated the code to move the image around while dragging.  My event handler in DropQueen took care of the drop.

Comment: I have to say the whole operation is less than ideal. But this did fix it for me, thanks.